# Count rows in a dataframe object with criteria in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Okay, I have a bit of a noob question, so please excuse me. I have a data frame object as follows:

```
| order_id| department_id|department    |  n|
|--------:|-------------:|:-------------|--:|
|        1|             4|produce       |  4|
|        1|            15|canned goods  |  1|
|        1|            16|dairy eggs    |  3|
|       36|             4|produce       |  3|
|       36|             7|beverages     |  1|
|       36|            16|dairy eggs    |  3|
|       36|            20|deli          |  1|
|       38|             1|frozen        |  1|
|       38|             4|produce       |  6|
|       38|            13|pantry        |  1|
|       38|            19|snacks        |  1|
|       96|             1|frozen        |  2|
|       96|             4|produce       |  4|
|       96|            20|deli          |  1|
```

This is the code I've used to arrive at this object:

```
temp5 <- opt %>%
    left_join(products,by="product_id")%>%
    left_join(departments,by="department_id") %>%
    group_by(order_id,department_id,department) %>%
    tally() %>%
    group_by(department_id)

kable(head(temp5,14))
```

As you can see, the object contains, departments present in each `Order_id`. Now, what I want to do is, I want to count the number of departments for each `order_id`

i tried using the `summarise()` method in the `dplyr` package, but it throws the following error:

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
>      Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "factor".

It seems so simple, but cant fig out how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: This is the code that I tried to run, post which I read about the `count()` function in the `plyr` package, i tried to use that as well, but that is of no use as it needs a data frame as input, whereas I only want to count the no of occurrences in the data frame

```
     temp5 <- opt %>%
     +     left_join(products,by="product_id")%>%
     +     left_join(departments,by="department_id") %>%
     +     group_by(order_id,department_id,department) %>%
     +     tally() %>%
     +     group_by(department_id) %>%
     +     summarise(count(department))
```

In the output, I need to know the average no. of departments ordered from in each order id, so i need something like this:

```
      Order_id | no. of departments
         1                3
         36               4
         38               4
         96               3
```

And then I should be able to plot using ggplot, `no. of orders` vs `no. of departments` in each order. Hope this is clear

Comment: what should be your output?

Comment: What command did you run exactly that gave you the error? When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Supply values for all the variables you list or leave out code that's not relevant.

Comment: Edited the question as requested, hope it is clear now

Comment: just do `data.frame(table(dat$order_id))`

Comment: `temp5 %>% count(order_id)`

Comment: @Onyambu Thank you it worked !